# Method Definition Not Found... automatic stub with Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, code-completion

I don't want to give up before asking, because this is basic functionality in any Java/.Net IDE. The compiler tells me:

```
Incomplete implementation of class...
Method definition for '-someMethod:' not found
```

but clicking, right-clicking, praying and Google searching have not gotten me to automatically create a method stub from this. **Can Xcode create a method stub for me and take me there?**

If not, why might that be (aside from "real programmers enjoy typing")?

**Edit:** I thought that <kbd>option-escape</kbd> basically solved this for me, but it does not. It doesn't seem to be aware of all (any?) of the interfaces my class implements.

Comment: `option-escape` (or just `escape`) has always found the method for me, but I haven't tested it with all possible scenarios. You don't have a syntax error in your `.h` file do you? That will break auto-complete.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert sorry, the question is asking about a case where the method body DOES NOT EXIST.

Comment: auto-complte doesn't use the method body. It uses the header files. Once a method is in the header, it will be available in auto-complete everywhere, including to write the method implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the OP (me) is talking about is in Java, where the interface is implicit. However, the case that is the same in Xcode is one where there is NO method yet defined in any interface.

AppCode handles this case, Xcode does not (unless somebody answers this question, but it's been here for a while):

[image: AppCode popover showing method creation]

**Later:** People have answered the question, but Xcode still doesn't do this.

Answer (score 4):

This might be an option to file a feature request to Apple.  Typically, I will design my @interface file and then do a copy/paste of the @interface to the @implementation keeping typing to an absolute minimum.

However, it would be nice to be able to click on the warning and have Xcode simply create the method at the botto of the @implementation.

NOTE: it is valid to keep the semicolon after the @implementation

```
@interface PCStackValue : NSObject <NSCoding, NSCopying>
{
}

- (id) initWithDisplayRadix:(int) newRadix;

@end

@implementation PCStackValue

- (id) initWithDisplayRadix:(int) newRadix;
{
   … do something;
}
@end
```

Comment: Really, the semicolon is okay? Regarding filing feature requests with Apple, I assume they read StackOverflow :) Problem is mostly with methods that are defined in another Protocol that I've said I will implement.

Comment: The simicolon is ignored in the implementation.  That was a big thing in NextStep 3.2 (I think, might have been 3.3) a few years back.  Quite a few years back.

Comment: Don't worry, Enrico, they don't have this feature in 2013 either.

Comment: 2014 calling. Still not here.

Comment: 2015? ah no, still not here

Answer (score 2):

I don't mind this behaviour. For one, the implementation does not necessarily exist as it might be dynamic. I also categorize my code using *#pragma mark - MyCategory* and want the implementations in specific locations in the source file.

However, I agree - I don't want to type the stub itself.

You can do it per method.
Go to your implementation file and start typing *- prefix* and hit ESC and you should see valid completions matching the prefix. You must start with typing a - or + for this to work, for instance methods and class methods respectively.

Sometimes you don't know what it is you are to implement! Open the Issue Navigator, and click the disclosure rectangle. There should be a line that says *Method declared here*. Click on it to see the method that lacks implementation.

Comment: I'm not talking about non-implemented methods. I'm talking about methods that do not yet exist in any interface yet. AppCode does this, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for doesn't exist. I just use auto-complete (it usually works for me) or copy/paste.

What makes you think Xcode would have a feature just because eclipse has it? Eclipse is ~10 years old, while Xcode is ~23 years old. Any features copied would most likely be in the other direction.

It would make a great feature request however. Perhaps opening the auto-complete menu on an empty line inside `@implementation .. @end` could give a list of not-yet-implemented methods.

But I'm not sure how well it would work in practice, because of `NSObject` categories. There might literally be *thousands* of "not-yet-implemented" methods in the auto-complete menu. But it could at least show some of the most likely ones.

It seems like this compile error/warning would also be a good candidate for the new "Fix It" feature.

Also: learn to type faster :p

Comment: Recent experience with AppCode -- hardly complete, but pretty good -- demonstrates just how wanting Xcode is. 23 years old, still crashes quite regularly, and doesn't do tons of great stuff. AppCode does what I'm asking for, by the way, and yes, it can figure it out thanks to Strong Typing....

Comment: Considering AppCode is 56MB and Xcode is 1,720MB... I'm not sure if it's fair to compare them. Sure AppCode does a few things nicely, but they have the luxury of focusing closely on a couple of individual features, without having to think about all the ones they don't need to write.

Comment: The elephant in the room is the possible superiority of managed languages, and I might even go further and point to statically AND strongly typed. Of course it's a quasi-religious debate, but one thing is for sure: if Xcode has limits, it's not because they don't have enough (or good enough) programmers working on it. But I digress...

Comment: +1 on a personal note, if I typed any faster, the keyboard would smoke.