# Automatically create skeleton methods for class/instance methods defined in header file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macros, code-completion

In XCode 4, is there a way to automatically create skeleton (i.e. basically copy and paste the signature over, with braces) whenever a new class or interface method is defined in the header file for a given class? Given the number of methods that I am writing at the moment this would save me a lot of time and reduce "incomplete implementation" warnings.

Comment: You _used to be able_ to do this with a script in Xcode 3. Apple removed that functionality for the New! Improved! More Fizzbang! Xcode 4. grumble rassum frassum grumble stupid _[file a radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn)_ Apple

Comment: possible dup [http://stackoverflow.com/q/2370209/971401](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2370209/971401).

Comment: @Vince thanks for pointing that one out. I was hoping there might be an Xcode4 specific answer.

Comment: comments on some answer aren't so far away (december 11), which probably corresponds to Xcode 4.